# Swift nested Json

Tags: json, swift, nested

I have a url that outputs a Json list of buses.

```
{"buses":
[
{"time_id”:"56555","bustime":"10:00 AM","price":"30.00","group_id":"1234"},
{"time_id":"56525",”bustime":"11:00 AM","price":"40.00","group_id":"1235"}
]}
```

The following has always worked for me to retrieve each bus as so:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.json_output_url.com:")

    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    {
        if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: [])) as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let BusArray = json["buses"] as? [NSDictionary]
            {
                for item in BusArray
                {
```

Now, the output has changed and the Buses array is nested in an outer array as so:

```
{"results":[
{"buses":
[
{"time_id”:"56555","bustime":"10:00 AM","price":"30.00","group_id":"1234"},
{"time_id":"56525",”bustime":"11:00 AM","price":"40.00","group_id":"1235"}
]}
]}
```

And I can no longer retrieve the Buses array because it is nested. I don't want to use a library such as Swiftyjson or anything, I just want to adjust my simple code to be able to retrieve stuff in a lower hierarchy. How is this achieved?

Comment: Your json output doesn't seem to be a valid json.

Comment: In my haste, I copied and pasted in a text editor and some of the double quotes changed to a rich format rendering them invalid. The correct syntax is:{"buses": [ {"time_id":"56555","bustime":"10:00 AM","price":"30.00","group_id":"1234"}, {"time_id":"56525","bustime":"11:00 AM","price":"40.00","group_id":"1235"} ]}

Comment: In any case you get the general idea - don't go for the exact exact code, the problem I'm tackling is the nesting part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I suppose you're using NSData(contentsOfURL:) for tests purposes. Be careful to use an asynchronous method instead in your real app.*

Here's the safe way to decode your new JSON data:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.json_output_url.com:"),
        JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),
        json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: []),
        dict = json as? [String: AnyObject],
        results = dict["results"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    for result in results {
        if let buses = result["buses"] as? [[String: String]] {
            for bus in buses {
                print(bus)
                if let time = bus["bustime"] {
                    print("Time: \(time)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked (although I did have to change String: String to String: AnyObject as well. But all is good now, your suggestion works! What is wrong with using NSData(contentsOfURL:) permanently in my real app? The output is from a web service that shouldn't change. If they do make changes they have to notify me in advance according to our contract.

Comment: You're welcome. :) The problem is that NSData works synchronously, so it will block the main thread (your app's UI) while downloading. This is bad user experience, and the App Store doesn't like it either. You should use an asynchronous method like NSURLSession instead, it will work in the background without freezing anything.

Comment: Ah I understand. In this case though, users have no choice. They absolutely need the answer from the service and will be requesting it explicitly with a button. I will have to get a spinner in there to keep them notified that my app hasn't crashed

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED2** answer:

```
if let BusArray = json["buses"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] // downcast to array of NSDictionary
{
    for item in BusArray
    {
        let timeId = item["time_id"] as? String
        let bustime = item["bustime"] as? String
        :
```

Comment: I'm not in front of the computer now, I can come back a little later to double check your answer, but I don't think it will work. I was able to get the item parts fine until now as well. The reason I'm unable to parse the Json anymore is because I don't reach my BusArray anymore as it is now in the inner level inside a new array called "results" as shown above

Comment: I also had "as? [NSDictionary]" So the change is only: "as? [[NSDictionary]]", right?

Comment: Yes. It's because buses are in array.

Comment: Ah! I understand. I'll test it later and let you know. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry, does not work! That is giving the following error: Cannot subscript a value of type 'Array<NSDictionary>' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: Edited once again. Array of `NSDictionary` changed to explicit dictionary of type array of `String: AnyObject`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112697/discussion-between-andrej-and-chaim-friedman).